# htaccess redirect subdomain to correct folder

Tags: .htaccess

Hi i need show different content for each subdomain **from document root subfolders**:

```
Read data from folder with subdomain name:

uu-u.domena.com  -> uu-u.domena.com/uu-u/index.php
xxx.domena.com  -> xxx.domena.com/xxx/index.php
doom.domena.com  -> doom.domena.com/doom/index.php

BUT i dont want to show folder name (show content from correct folder)

doom.domena.com/doom/index.php -> doom.domena.com/index.php
xox.domena.com/xox/index.php -> xox.domena.com/index.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.boo\.loc$   [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. 
RewriteRule ^$ http://%1.boo.loc/%1/  [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Only this code i have got

Comment: RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.boo\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI}?folder=%1 [L,QSA]

Comment: It is correct example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule already points into the right direction. It captures the sub-domain part and uses it in the target URL `%1`.

Things to improve are

- there are too many flags, which are not needed (just `L` flag)
- append the requested path (`%{REQUEST_URI}`)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.boo\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Small error change ^ to ^$ in RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L] but then works ok. Thanks

Comment: This works for me bu thanks for help.
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.boo\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI}?folder=%1 [L,QSA]

Comment: The first pattern `^$` matches only an empty (home page) request, This is why it doesn't work with `x.php`. Why do you need the `folder=%1` part?

Comment: I need load some data from php but dont want cut in php file from url

Comment: Thansk for help! Again.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
# redirect subdomain to subdomain folder in *.domain.com document root
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.boo\.loc$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /%1%{REQUEST_URI}?folder=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks for the help.